# MvvmCross.Sqlite 'System.DllNotFoundException' in SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.dll

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, mvvmcross

I've added the MvvmCross.Sqlite Plugin to my project. Also the SQLite Extension for UWP.

I register the Factory Interface:

```
            Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxSqliteConnectionFactory, WindowsSqliteConnectionFactory>();
```

And resolve it in my connector class:

```
private readonly IMvxSqliteConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

        public SqliteConnectionCreator(IMvxSqliteConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
        {
            this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;

            CreateDb();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Creates the config and establishe the connection to the sqlite database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Established SQLiteConnection.</returns>
        public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return connectionFactory.GetConnection(new SqLiteConfig(OneDriveAuthenticationConstants.DB_NAME, false));
        }

        private void CreateDb()
        {
            using (var db = connectionFactory.GetConnection(OneDriveAuthenticationConstants.DB_NAME))
            {
                db.CreateTable<Account>();
                db.CreateTable<Payment>();
                db.CreateTable<RecurringPayment>();
                db.CreateTable<Category>();
            }
        }
```

But as soon as I wanna access either the get Connection or the current platform it throughs an exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.dll
```

The type of the injected factory is WindowsSqliteConnectionFactory what's correct I think.
My projects have a reference to the mvvmplugin and sqlite.net-pcl, sqlite.net.core-pcl,sqlite.net.async-pcl.

Do I have to register something else in mvx? Or how comes that the plattformspecific Factory (WindowsSqliteConnectionFactory) doesn't have a plattform?

Comment: If anyone is facing the same issue, you should add a reference to Visual c++ runtime for universal windows, as mentionned here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36543598/1166703