# Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'

Tags: visual-studio, reference, nuget, uwp

After I add 2 libraries from Nuget to my project I receive follow error:

```
Error       Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\Horcrux7\.nuget\packages\runtime.any.System.Diagnostics.Tools\4.0.1\lib\netcore50\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
C:\Users\Horcrux7\.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tools\4.0.0\lib\netcore50\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll App1
```

How can I solve this version conflict?

I have only a very small single UWP project.

Comment: Are you referencing some prerelease nuget packages?

Comment: I add 2 references to 2 different libraries which are compiled again different versions. This should not be very exotic. There should be a general construct to solve this conflicts.

Comment: Maybe you can consider downgrading one of your referenced libraries. I'm seeing the same error reference System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0. However, after downgrade to 4.0.0, everything works fine.

Comment: No, downgrade is not possible because older versions are not compatible with UWP.

Comment: Did you find this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851012/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-in-universal-windows-app-running-on-mobile userful? Does not seem like a good solution, but works for me.

Comment: This is not a solution. First it must be do on every system. Also on a the central build system. To replace files in the nuget package manager seems also a bad idea. The second answer with filtering does not help because there is no the duplicated references to see.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem has solve it self. An update to the latest version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform has solved it.

It look like that library A was compiled against version 5.1.0 and library B was compiled against version 5.2.2. Because my project was on version 5.1.0 there was a conflict situation. I does not understand why I have no conflict if I switch the UWP version.

If I use the library B with the old UWP version there was also no conflict.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Same DLL. Same 5.1.0/5.2.2 conflict. I was surprised that this version mismatch is not solved by Visual Studio / nuget by updating Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to 5.2.2 at package install/restore time.

Answer (score 14):

Just in case it may be useful to others encountering the same error - "Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path..." - which can be caused by a variety of reasons related to the labyrinth of NuGet packages, one remedy for such NuGet related errors is [clearing the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache), or simply deleting the problematic NuGet package folder: C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\

This is based on my own experience of dealing with similar errors including this particular one.

**Edit (2018-07-22)**:
I have been having good luck in dealing with this and similar problems by simply restarting Visual Studio. Probably Microsoft is getting to this bug finally. I get this kind of problems only when building a release version.

Comment: I do the same think and it's only one what's help me but i got other difference in path than package version incompatibility

Comment: @W0RT4 It happens repeatedly when I build a release version of a UWP app. I now delete only C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.portable.compatibility, and it always works.  I need to find a permanent solution.

Comment: try to remove project.nuget.targets file in my case it helps (i hope permanently)

Comment: I got this error while building a release version, using VS 2019 version 16.2.3, even though nuget packages for all references were latest. But I was running other project in which I had an older nuget package. I closed that project and then I could create the package successfully.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had "Any CPU" option selected so it was compiling the same library for both versions. Selecting x64 solved the problem for me.

Comment: I was getting this on a Xamarin.Forms UWP project release build and had a similar issue. The project properties Build section had x64 selected while I was trying to build/run as x86.  Matching the two settings as, Usman pointed out, cleared the issue.

Comment: I also encountered this issue on UWP and MVVM cross.

Answer (score 3):

I did a downgrade Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite to 2.2.6 then solved problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following in VS2019

1. Update `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` using Tools-->Nuget Package Manager--> Manage Nuget Package for Solutions
2. Tools-->Nuget Package Manager--> Package Manager Settings-->Clear All Nuget Cache(s)
3. Delete the files under:

```
<package Name>\bin\x86\Release
<package Name>\bin\x64\Release
<package Name>\bin\Arm\Release
```

4. Build--> Clean Solution for each version, Release x86 etc

Finally worked for me. If this still fails, building a package using VS2017 may work.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform version 6.2.12

My project was at D:\

Problem solved when I moved project to C:\

I didn't understand the cause though :(  Path at D:\ was a short and all ASCII path.

Answer (score 0):

update the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite version 3.1.2 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For `Default.rd.xml`, I removed the duplicate from my Unit Test project and then was able to run my tests.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had 2 instances of visual studio. I closed both and re-opened the project that I needed to publish and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while trying to publish UWP package.
Solved it by switching the VS to Release, restart VS and Publish the package.