# build for upload failed ( Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path )

Tags: uwp

While I could build each release config separately, I could not create a release/upload package using the "Create App Package" wizard.

Already read related topics. ([Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593840/payload-contains-two-or-more-files-with-the-same-destination-path-system-diagno))

I tried

1. deleting the **obj** folder
2. deleting the **bin** folder
3. clean solution for each build config
4. cleared nuget cache

but the build still failed with the same errors.

The project use to be able to build before and no nuget package has changed ever since ( they are also the newest version). I compared the build setting of each (x86/x64/arm). They are almost identical except the Platform target (x86/x64/arm) and Output path.

In the logs, the path of the DLLs are all different only by "-aot" part. They all looks like to be standard library DLLs. By watching the build running, it seems that the issue only occurs starting on the 2nd (x64) configuration.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'clrcompression.dll', but they are different sizes. Source files: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64\nativeassets\uap10.0.15138\clrcompression.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\nativeassets\uap10.0.15138\clrcompression.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Microsoft.CSharp.dll', but they are different sizes. Source files: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64\lib\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll', but they have different content. Source files: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64\lib\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll', but they are different sizes. Source files: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64\lib\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1111: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.AppContext.dll', but they have different content. Source files: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.AppContext.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.AppContext.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Buffers.dll', but they have different content. Source files: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Buffers.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6086,5): error APPX1112: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Buffers.dll
```

I have no idea whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click in Proyect > Manage NuGet Package > Package Sources > Unckeck "Source of package system"

[image: Error Visual Studio Duplicated libraries]

Answer (score 0):

I loaded up the Project in Visual Studio 2022 preview 3.1 and it builds the package successfully again. It looks like to be Visual Studio related issue. Visual Studio 2019 is so unpredictable!