# Two DLLs trying to be copied with the same name

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am getting the following build error:

```
 Microsoft.Build.Msix.Packaging.targets(1370, 5): [APPX1101] Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\Bryan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webview2\1.0.1018-prerelease\lib\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
C:\Users\Bryan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webview2\1.0.1018-prerelease\runtimes\win-x64\native_uap\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
```

This happened after installing the Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT package in my winui3 app and a class library.

Comment: May sound trivial, but have you tried restarting Visual Studio? [Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48435111/16680216) maybe the accepted answer could be useful if you haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @The2Step tried that but still not working.  same issue happening in Rider.