# .NET MAUI Build Error somerandomstuff1084

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

When I run my MAUI Blazor project without any packages installed, it runs fine. The trouble starts when I try to download EF Core packages (specifically base, tools, SqlServer, and design). I started by trying the prerelease version 7.0.0-3.22175.1, but kept getting this error "Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path {ProjectName}.deps.json. This lead me to look at this thread [Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38593840/12498326)
I tried adjusting the CPU to both x86 and x64, I've tried deleting my NuGet packages cache, I've also tried downgrading EF Core to the latest stable (6.0.4), but now I'm receiving this error:

Error   NETSDK1130  Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.winmd cannot be referenced. Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting .NET 5 or higher is not supported. For more information, see https://aka.ms/netsdk1130 {ProjectName} C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300-preview.22204.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets

UPDATE: I think I've nailed this down to some type of conflict between EF Core base package and either Tools or Design being used with it. When I run with only EF Core, the project builds just fine. When I try to include EITHER Tools or Design, that's when the payload duplicate error comes up.