# Xamarin WinPhone - Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'sqlite3.dll'

Tags: dll, xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.winphone

When I try to run the Windows App to "Emulator 8.1 1080P 5.5 Inch" or any of the emulator for WinPhone, I've got this error

> Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path
>   'sqlite3.dll'

I have tried following this solution [Unable to load DLL sqlite3 in Universal Windows App running on Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851012/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-in-universal-windows-app-running-on-mobile) but it didn't work in my case.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? Thank you so much for the advice and help.